# Twitter Bootstrap nested form

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I just started with Twitter Bootstrap and can't find out how to do this. I want to create a form with the following layout:

```
+---------+ +---------------------------+
| input 1 | |                           |
+---------+ |                           |
+---------+ |                           |
| input 2 | |      textarea             |
+---------+ |                           |
+---------+ |                           |
| input 3 | |                           |
+---------+ +---------------------------+
```

I can find some examples on how to nest controls horizontal with the grid system (like [this](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem)), but for the vertical nesting of controls I couldn't find anything.

Is it possible to create a layout like this without using a table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap the 3 in a `<div class="span2">`

And the textarea in a `<div class="span5">`

Or whatever ratio, brings about your desired result....

Like So...

```
<div class="row-fluid span12">
  <div class='span2'>
       <div control-group....>
       <input...> 
       <input...>
       <input...>
       </div>
 </div>
 <div class="span5">
      <textarea></textarea>
 </div>
</div>
```